# Windows DNS Local and Internet domain

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, internal-dns, dns-hosting

We have our company domain hosted on the internet, call it mycompany.com

We have all our DNS records hosted on the internet for this. However, what we want is for one hostname to have a different address when we do the lookup from inside the network.

Our Windows network has a mycompany.local domain.

What we want is hostname.mycompany.com to resolve to our external router address outside the network and we want

hostname.mycompany.com to resolve to a local server address from inside the network.

Our dns server is currently 2012r2.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a DNS zone on your internal DNS server named hostname.mycompany.com.

Create an "empty" A record in the zone with the ip address of the internal server you want this name to resolve to.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Congratulations on the 100k Joe :)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that it had "rolled over". I knew it was close but didn't know when it would happen.